# How could I intercept all calls to commands from a specific powershell module?

Tags: powershell

So I would like to implement a module to "intercept" all calls to a given target module in order to track calls to each command and throttle them based on a specific policy. How can I do this in powershell? Do I have to implement a custom host?

Answer (score 0):

Create a proxy functions for functions exported from the module and "throttle" them inside those proxy functions.

For an automatic creation of the proxy functions, see `MetaProgramming Module` at the end of this article: [Extending and/or Modifing Commands with Proxies](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/extending-andor-modifing-commands-with-proxies/).